# Изменения в Ide не отображаются в проекте

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, ide

Каким то неведомым для меня образом - код написанный в vsCode перестал взаимодействовать с запущенным приложением. Любые взаимодействия с кодом в проекте не отображаются. В приложении скрин. С чем это может быть связанно? Заранее спасибо.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не добавляйте код картинкой.

Comment: Когда разворачивали проект использовали npx create-react-app?